# Lua: recursive function builts wrong table - pil4

Tags: recursion, lua

while working on the exercise 2.2 of "programming in Lua 4" I do have to create a function to built all permutations of the numbers 1-8. I decided to use Heaps algorithm und made the following script. I´m testing with numbers 1-3.

In the function I store the permutations as tables {1,2,3} {2,1,3} and so on into local "a" and add them to global "perm". But something runs wrong and at the end of the recursions I get the same permutation on all slots. I can´t figure it out. Please help.

```lua
          function generateperm (k,a)
            if k == 1 then
              perm[#perm + 1] = a          -- adds recent permutation to table
              io.write(table.unpack(a))    -- debug print. it shows last added one
              io.write("\n")               -- so I can see the algorithm works fine
            else
              for i=1,k do
                generateperm(k-1,a)
                if k % 2 == 0 then         -- builts a permutation
                  a[i],a[k] = a[k],a[i]
                else
                  a[1],a[k] = a[k],a[1]
                end
              end
            end
          end
        --
        perm = {}
        generateperm(3,{1,2,3})               -- start
        --
        for k,v in ipairs (perm) do           -- prints all stored permutations
          for k,v in ipairs(perm[k]) do       -- but it´s 6 times {1,2,3}
            io.write(v)       
          end
          io.write("\n")
        end
```

debug print:

```
123
213
312
132
231
321
123
123
123
123
123
123
```

Comment: Two things: 1. You're using the same `k,v` variables in the nested `for .. do` loop. 2. That table that you're passing along is a reference, so all the `perm[#perm + 1] = a` assignments end up pointing to the same table that is modified over and over. For this to work you want to make a copy of `a` that you then add to `perm`.

Comment: Thank you Erwin,
I´ll give it a try. Probably you´re right. Have to get some sleep now, but then...

Comment: Thanks a lot Erwin! The reference thing is the answer! of course! :-)